output's bitrate is vary from specified bitrate for ogg file using ffmpeg
I'm trying to convert a wav file into an ogg file. I set bitrate=320k, but the output's bitrate is about 289. this is command that I use:
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 320k output.ogg

do you know why this happens?

Please Edit your question and provide the full ffmpeg command you are using,  and also the output of lsb_release -a

Do you experience the same effect when adding in: -c:a libvorbis ?

@andrew.47 Yes, the outputs are same, but based on this link 'Vorbis codec is natively variable bitrate codec' and It makes sense that the set bitrate is different from the output value
